# How to expand partition in Ubuntu 16.04 dual-boot system

Tags: partitioning

I have Windows 7 64-bit & Ubuntu 16.04 dual-boot. Ubuntu is installed on 29.9 Gb. I have created 149 Gb of unallocated space from inside Windows and want to expand my Ubuntu to occupy this space.

[image]

How should I proceed?

Comment: Your image shows what I assume to be a USB flash drive. There's no room to expand there... and hopefully you're not trying to run Ubuntu from a flash drive. Please update your question with more details about your configuration, and a screenshot of /dev/sda. Attach additional images at http://imgur.com/ and leave us the link.

Comment: imgur images at: https://imgur.com/a/HsgtY - first image is ubunto partitioning, second is windows partitions

Comment: Edit your question to include the images :) It looks like you have Windows on /dev/sda and Ubuntu on /dev/sdb. You won't be able to expand the Ubuntu partition onto a different drive. You could *move or copy* the partition onto the unallocated space on sda, but then you would need to change your boot setup.

Comment: Is sdb an internal hard drive? If not, you don't really have a dual boot.

Comment: I have only one HDD, I'm using dual-boot and have installed Ubuntu 16.04. I go inside and use gparted, then I get these 2 images, one depics my ubuntu installation and the other my win7 ntfs installation.

Comment: Is sdb a small SSD used for Windows to quick boot that you reformatted. If so it is plenty large for / (root), but then you should use space on HDD for /home or a /mnt/data with all the normal data you have in /home. To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify... it looks like your hardware configuration was originally Windows, installed on the internal hard disk, and that also used an internal 30GB SSD used as a cache to speed up Windows operations. At some point either the internal hard disk was upgraded, and/or Windows reinstalled, and the 30GB SSD was reformatted (and not used as a Windows cache).

It looks like your Ubuntu installation on /dev/sdb is a fresh minimal installation on a 30GB <strike>USB flash</strike> internal SSD drive, and can't be extended there.

The free 149GB unallocated space is on a 1TB drive as /dev/sda.

Although there's a way to copy/paste partitions between drives using `gparted`, I'm not sure it would be worth it in this case.

I'd recommend just reinstalling Ubuntu in a dual-boot configuration on /dev/sda using the 149GB unallocated space <strike>with the USB flash drive removed from its port</strike>, and reformatting /dev/sdb 30GB SSD with a NTFS partition that can be shared between operating systems.

**Update #1:**

To move your swap from /dev/sdb to /dev/sda...

- shrink your Windows C: by 8GB using Windows Disk Management app (already done)
- boot Ubuntu
- In `gparted`...

  - create an 8GB swap partition in the unallocated space just created, note what partition # it is (ie:/dev/sda5)
- In `terminal`...

  - type `swapoff -a`
  - type `mkswap /dev/sdaX` (replacing X with the partition number from the previous step)
  - **copy** the new UUID to the clipboard
  - type `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab`
  - find the line that looks something like this:

  `UUID=xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx    none    swap     sw     0       0`

  - carefully replace the xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx with a **paste** from the clipboard
  - save the file and quit gedit
  - type `swapon -a`
- In `gparted`...

  - wipe out /dev/sdb (30GB SSD) and create a new NTFS partition

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59889/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-how-to-expand-partition-in-ubuntu-16-04-dual-bo).